# Permitir a um usuário visualizar stored procedures criadas por outros usuários

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, procedure, stored-procedures

Tenho um banco de dados MySQL populado com algumas *stored procedures*. O problema é que dois usuários diferentes criaram diversas procedures, de forma que somente o usuário que criou a stored procedure pode ver o seu conteúdo. Dentro deste contexto, eu gostaria de que todos os dois usuários pudessem ver todas as procedures, ou seja, aquelas que ele criou e as outras criadas pelo outro usuário.

Como isto seria possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa dar a permissão (ou privilégio) [`EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) para ambos os usuários, sobre as *procedures* um do outro.

O comando [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) pode ser executado de forma a dar permissões para execução de qualquer rotinas de um banco de dados.

Exemplo:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON banco.* TO 'usuario'@'host';
```

Além disso, para que um usuário possa ver o código de uma *procedure* criada por outro, ele precisa do privilégio `SELECT` na tabela `mysql.proc`. Isso pode ser conformado na documentação do comando [`SHOW PROCEDURE CODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-procedure-code.html).

Resumindo, a listagem de objetos de um banco de dados ou do código de um deles não é sempre feita através de permissões diretamente relacionadas ao objeto. Portanto, verifique os privilégios como `SELECT` nas tabelas de controle do MySQL e nas tabelas do banco de dados atual.

Comment: Não deu certo, meu usuário continua sem visualizar as permissões do outro usuário. Engraçado que fiz este teste em localhost e os usuários estão conseguindo visualizar tranquilamente, porém em produção não estão mais.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Não sei se entendi. Visualizar as permissões? Qual é exatamente o objetivo? Listar procedures? Ver código-fonte? Executá-las? Algo que geralmente causa problemas é com relação ao `host` informado no comando `grant`. Você deve informar o host no qual o usuário se loga e não o host onde está o servidor. MySQL. Outra coisa é que pode haver falta de um outro privilégio para o usuário simplesmente listar as informações do outro. Tente adicionar também o privilégio `SELECT`.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo visualizar o código fonte das procedures criadas pelo outro usuário, mesmo que o meu usuário seja super administrador do banco de dados, ou seja, tenha permissão para tudo, inclusive grant. Ao executar o grant tenho substituído 'localhost' por '%', ou seja 'user'@'%'.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Se um administrador não tem permissão para ver, então há um problema com o ambiente. Tentou reiniciar a instância do MySQL?

Comment: @etluiz não, pois este servidor está sendo executado em ambiente de produção, teria que ser realizado em outro momento. Você acredita que reiniciar o serviço do mysql poderia sumir com este problema?

Comment: @etluiz graças a sua sugestão de permitir privilégios SELECT o problema foi resolvido. Por favor, edite a sua resposta informando a concessão de permissão através de SELECT para que eu possa avaliá-la como correta.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Que bom que resolveu! Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado.